# Listing GPA on resumes or job applications

Tags: gpa

When people list GPA on a resume, Linkedin or job/internship/graduate program application what GPA is it: the CGPA or most recent semester's/semesters' GPA? For some graduate programs only the last year/2 year GPA is considered but when it is not explicitly stated that the GPA for only certain semesters is relevant then what GPA would be typically stated?

Comment: Cumulative GPA. It might seem dishonest to cherry-pick the best GPA or only show a GPA from a single semester.

Comment: Agreed. I would assume cumulative.